# Modify objective function for equal solution distribution

Tags: linear-programming, modeling

I have the following question. I have a LP with the objective function.

$\max\sum_{i\in I}^{}\sum_{p\in P}^{}sales_{ip}$

Here, the number of sales over all individuals $i$ is to be maximized for all periods $p$. So far so good. The model works and maximizes the sales. But it happens from time to time that e.g. individual 1 has 10 sales and the others 0, while it also happens that all have 2. In the sum, however, always ten. How can we force that it is as balanced as possible over all individuals? So that there is not the extreme with "one has everything", but that it is more or less equally distributed?

Answer (score 4):

Two approaches:

1. Use an interior point algorithm (without crossover) to naturally encourage balanced solutions.
2. Use multiple objectives.  The primary objective is to maximize sales.  After optimizing the primary objective, impose an additional constraint ("objective cut") that forces the sales to be at least the maximum just found.  The secondary objective can be to minimize the maximum (alternatively, maximize the minimum).  Now optimize the secondary objective subject to the original constraints and the objective cut.

Comment: Worth noting: this implicitly assumes that any improvement in overall sales is more important than any improvement in balance (which is consistent with the example in the question). If balance is worth sacrificing some overall sales, a composite objective function is another approach.